# Многослойный персептрон Keras: в каком виде должны подаваться данные на вход нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь освоить библиотеку Keras. Посмотрел различные примеры типа MNIST, Cifar10 и подобные "Hello, world!" примеры обучения нейронных сетей. Однако из этих примеров непонятно, как обучить нейронную сеть на собственном наборе данных. Допустим, я хочу создать многослойный персептрон. Добавление слоев, компиляция модели и ее обучения более-менее понятны, на данный момент непонятно одно: в каком виде должны подаваться данные на вход нейронной сети? То есть что представляют из себя те же `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test` из примеров с обучением на наборе MNIST?

Буду благодарен любому примеру, дающему понимание работы с нейронными сетями в Keras.

Comment: А что из себя представляет ваш собственный набор входных (`X_train`) и выходных (`y_train`) данных?

Comment: Чтобы разобратся с подготовкой входных данных, мне помогла эта статья: https://www.asozykin.ru/deep_learning/2018/01/06/how-to-prepare-image-dataset-for-keras

Answer (score 1):

Обычно на вход нейронным сетям подается вектор (1D) или N-мерная матрица которые содержат числовые значения в ячейках.

Алгоритмы машинного обучения основанные на методе градиентного спуска ожидают нормализованные (с медианой нормального распределения в области `0` и приблизительно одинаковыми значениями стандартного отклонения до `1`) значения по всем осям (`features`) матрицы. Иначе метод градиентного спуска может не сойтись или сходиться очень медленно или алгоритмы будут делать плохие предсказания.

Т.е. в тех случаях, когда в разных столбцах находятся данные разных порядков (например в одном столбце диапазон значений: [0, 1], а в другом: [0, 10<sup>7</sup>] ) очень часто входные матрицы приходится нормализовать, т.е. приводить к диапазону: `[0, 1]` или `[-1, 1]`.

[Сравнение различных методов нормализации данных](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py)

Answer (score 0):

В MNIST данные подаются в таком виде:

`X_train` - это массив изображений, каждое изображение 28x28 пикселов, т.е. 784.

`y_train` - это массив чисел от 0 до 9, результаты по которым тренируется CNN собственно.

В тест сете все так же, только там происходит не тренировка, а получение и проверка результатов.

Можно взять готовый код, например, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py и изучить все данные с помощью

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

отвечу не профессиональным слогом :)

- на вход сети можно подать только цифры в виде скаляра, вектора, тензора, то есть ND-мерные массивы, т.к. нейронные сети работают только с сигналом (цифра) и весовым коэффициентом (тоже цифра), ну и подстроечный резистор - bias, поднимающий-опускающий значение вывода нейрона(цифра).
- сами наборы также являются массивом, обьединяющим эти входные наборы, возможно, что в варианте также разбитые на batches
- текст и слова, как правило превращаются также коды, вы потом увидите и поймёте непонятный смысл превращения слов-знаков в цифры word2seq, либо кодирование to_categorical выходного слоя, потому, что на выходе сети тоже массив цифр.
- возможно, для облегчения работы пользователя вскоре появится input-слой именно для char-emmbedding, куда можно будет просто передавать строку
- еще существенным моментом являются характеристики input_shape=(), указывающие размерность данных на входе, я бы посоветовал "потренироваться на кошках", то есть задаёте свои маленькие массивы разных размерностей и подаёте их на свой input либо dense-слой

ну и собственно, про Xtrain, Xtest
- когда вы тренируете сеть, она "подстраивается" на имеющихся данных до 100% совпадения

- поэтому она разбивается на данные тренируемые(Xtrain) и тестовые(Xtest) и проверочные(Xvalidate)
- а смысл в том, что тестовые данные НЕ участвовали в тренировке